# Postgres Update Statement: how to set a column's value only if the column name contains a certain substring?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Each of the following tables ['table1', 'table2'] are part of the public schema, knowing that each table may contain multiple columns containing the substring 'substring' in the name for Example let's look at the following :

- Table_1 (xyz, xyz_**substring**,...some_other_columns... abc,
  abc_**substring**)
- Table_2 (xyz, xyz_**substring**,..some_other_columns... abc,
  abc_**substring**)

I am coming to this from a pythonic way of thinking, but basically, how could one execute a statement without knowing exactly what to set since the columns we need to target need to meet a certain criteria ?

I had the idea to add a another loop over the column names of the current table and check if the name meets the criteria. then execute the query but It feels very far away from optimal.

```
DO $$
declare
    t text;
    tablenames  TEXT ARRAY  DEFAULT  ARRAY['table_1', 'table_2'];
BEGIN
    FOREACH t IN ARRAY tablenames
    LOOP
        raise notice 'table(%)', t;
        -- update : for all the column that contain 'substring' in their names set a value  
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the answer **@Stefanov.sm** , i followed exactly your thought and was able to base your logic to have just one statement :

```
DO $$
declare
    t text;
    tablenames  TEXT ARRAY  DEFAULT  ARRAY['table_1', 'table_2'];
    dynsql text;
    colname text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH t IN ARRAY tablenames LOOP
        raise notice 'table (%)', t;
        dynsql := format('update %I set', t);
        for colname in select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = t
            loop
                if colname like '%substring%' then
                    dynsql := concat(dynsql,format(' %I = ....whatever expression here (Make sure to check if you should use Literal formatter %L if needed) ....,',colname,...whateverargs...));
                end if;
            end loop; 
      dynsql := concat(dynsql,';'); -- not sure if required.
      raise notice 'SQL to execute (%)', dynsql;
      execute dynsql;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Extract the list of columns of each table and then try dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the list of columns of each table and then format/execute dynamic SQL. Something like

```sql
DO $$
declare
    t text;
    tablenames text[] DEFAULT ARRAY['table_1', 'table_2'];
    dynsql text;
    colname text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH t IN ARRAY tablenames LOOP
        raise notice 'table (%)', t;
        for colname in select column_name 
          from information_schema.columns 
          where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = t loop
            if colname ~ '__substring$' then
                dynsql := format('update %I set %I = ...expression... ...other clauses if any...', t, colname);
                raise notice 'SQL to execute (%)', dynsql;
                execute dynsql;
            end if;
        end loop;        
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

This will cause excessive bloat so do not forget to `vacuum` your tables. If your tables' schema is not `public` then edit the select from `information_schema` accordingly. You may use `pg_catalog` resource instead of `information_schema` too.